# mvc how to display datetime in date format

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery-datatables-rails

In Mvc how to display DateTime in Date Format Like
1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM,  This Date Format I Wana to show 1/1/2015

```
<table id="table_id">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>EmpId</td>
</tr>
    <tbody>

     @foreach (var ee in Model.GetEmployeeFromHybridge)
            { <td>@ee.date</td>}
    </tbody>
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').dataTable();

    })
```

Comment: You can format the date inline  `@ee.date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: how it will take oveloade parameters

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Nkosi its Throgh an Error as .Tostring No Overload methode its Takes

Comment: Then `ee.date` is not a `DateTime` as that method exists on `DateTime` object. You can go the other route of using `@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",ee.date)`

Comment: @Nkosi          public Nullable<DateTime> date { get; set; }
  Its Datetime

Comment: You did not indicate it was nullable before. Try `@ee.date.HasValue?ee.date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : ""`

Answer (score 0):

You can just format a dateTime with .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Be sure your field type is DateTime.

Here's a link showing way to format date and time.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings